# Regular expression to validate string format to specific length with csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a regular expression which validates a text box to have only digits with length 5 or 9. I found the below regular expression to get this done

```
^\d{1,5}([,]\d{5})*$
```

but it could not fix my requirement correctly, Can any one please help me in modifying or writing a new regular expression which supports below pattern.

- 09103,09101,     **valid**    *(ending with comma)*
- 09103,09101      **valid**    *(not ending with comma)*
- 12345,1234567    **Invalid**  *(should not support if 1st digit is length 5 and 2nd less than 9)*
- 12345,123456789  **valid**     *(must support only digit length 5 or 9)*

Comment: is this `22,67567`, `45365,` valid?

Comment: it seems right, can you give code on how you are checking ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj : it is wrong. first value is 22 and it should not match. we want either 12345 or 123456789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the part which was preceded by comma to optional, so that it would match only `12345` or `12345,`

```
^(?:\d{5}|\d{9})(?:,(?:\d{5}|\d{9}))?,?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/19)

Comment: seems to be working perfectly. let me have some more scenario tested. will mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
var lines = new []
{
    "09103,09101,",
    "09103,09101",
    "12345,1234567",
    "12345,123456789",
    "12345"
};

var re = new Regex(@"^\d{1,5}(,(\d{5}|\d{9}))?,?$");

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", line, re.IsMatch(line) ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
}
```

**Output**

```
09103,09101, = Valid
09103,09101 = Valid
12345,1234567 = Invalid
12345,123456789 = Valid
12345 = Valid
```

You can run it here: [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f63dHB)

Comment: can u alter to this please. if i give just 12345 also it should work

Comment: I added the "just 12345" condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for your exact test cases.

```
^\d{5},?$|^\d{5},\d{5},?$|^\d{5},\d{9},?$
```

It uses the `|` character to separate 'alternative' patterns, read it as "or". I.e.

```
^\d{5}$  OR  ^\d{5},\d{5}$  OR  ^\d{5},\d{9}$
```

Comment: if i give the value as 12345 or 12345, should also work but it is not working with your solution.

Comment: Updated to include the single five digit number case. Are there other cases too? Like a single nine digit number or two nine digit numbers?